# Why documentation etc. use @ in place of * for multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

Why many documentations and blog posts use @ in place of * (multiplication operator) in python.
[Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html#scipy.optimize.linprog) is an example. They use `C@x` instead of `c*x` (also found in the next lines in the page). Is @ used to say it is vector multiplication etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They write it like that because the underlying objects are matrices and/or vectors, not scalars.

The operator `@` indicates a [matrix multiplication](https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/), and hooks into the datamodel [`__matmul__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__matmul__), which has a different behaviour to `*` operation i.e. [`__mul__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mul__).

The most common case you will see is with numpy ndarrays, where `@` is matrix multiplication and `*` is element-wise multiplication:

```
>>> A = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
>>> A
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
>>> A @ A
array([[ 2,  3],
       [ 6, 11]])
>>> A * A
array([[0, 1],
       [4, 9]])
```